# plumbing two sinks into one drain kitchen and bathroom vanity and have one vent

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, kitchens

can I tie my  kitchen sink  into my bathroom vanity sink drain, use same drain for both sinks, they both align on same wall on opposite sides thanks open wall construction, everything is new, and its the only two inch drain available of course there is a vent , this is all that will be tied into this drain, the two sinks, kitchen and bathroom sink, back to back thanks.. monty

Comment: What size is the vent pipe and how far is it from both fixtures?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be an issue, especially if you're not using both sinks heavily at once. Obviously keep in mind that it's ideal to have a bit more drainage than the 2 sinks combined, just in case.

Keep in mind there may be varying codes depending on local which affect this solution.